# How To Deploy PyS60 Apps To The Ovi Store?

Tags: python, symbian, s60, pys60, ovi

I'm developing some PyS60 applications and today I've seen that it's possible to deploy them to the Ovi Store according to the [Release Notes](https://garage.maemo.org/frs/download.php/7494/release_notes_2.0.0.txt)([Discussion Thread](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?193112-Python-for-S60-2.0.0-released) too):

> - All the Pyds that have zero UID will be assigned with the applications UID at the time of packaging.
>     As a result, Python applications can now be symbian signed. This opens the door for submitting Python applications to OVI Store.

But where I can get a tutorial or some help about how to do this?

Comment: With PyS60 you could embed python runtime inside your app and try to submit that as one package. PySide has dependency on Qt so that's more complicated. But if you manage to figure out an easy way, I still have a few PyS60 apps I would like to upload to Ovi Store :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, i ask so many time to add Python as an authorized Language for OVI. But the only answer i got, is that to not loose developper they focus their store on One language. App can be signed, but they will probably not accept them